# Read save data from files in nodeJS synchronously

Tags: node.js

I'm new to nodeJS and sync/async code logic.
I would like to read some text files and put their contents in a global array that I want to read later to save it in a database. Here is my code:

```
function getData2() {
    glob("Massachusetts_*.txt", 'nonull', function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            process.exit(1);
        }
        var results = [];
        files.forEach(function (file) {
            fs.readFile(file, function (err, html) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error reading " + file, err);
                    process.exit(1);
                } else {
                    const td = [html];
                    const dom = new JSDOM(`<table><tr>${td.join("")}</tr></table>`);
                    const frag = dom.window.document;
                    const data = [...frag.querySelectorAll("td")].reduce((ob, td) => {
                        const a = td.innerHTML.trim();
                        ob.push(a);
                        return ob;
                    }, []);
                    console.log(data);
                    results.push(data);
                }
            });
        });
        console.log(results);
    });
}
```

`console.log(data)` indeed shows the data read from each file but it is the results array that is supposed to accumulate the data that shows as `[]` empty. Any help here please?

Comment: Use fs.readFileSync instead of fs.readFile, and everything should be more straightforward.

Comment: It sends [] as result.

Comment: I did a quick check some minutes ago. I changed the code a little.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the code slightly.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const glob = require("glob");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

function getData2()
{
    glob("Massachusetts_*.txt", {
        nodir: true
    }, function (err, files)
    {

        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            process.exitCode = 1;
            return;
        }

        const results = [];
        files.forEach(function (file)
        {
            const html = fs.readFileSync(file, {encoding: "utf-8"});
            const td = [html];

            // <td> </td> was missing
            const dom = new JSDOM(`<table><tr><td>${td.join("")}</td></tr></table>`);

            const frag = dom.window.document;
            const tdList = [...frag.querySelectorAll("td")];

            const data = tdList.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) =>
            {
                const a = currentValue.innerHTML.trim();
                accumulator.push(a);
                return accumulator;
            }, [])
            console.log(data);
            results.push(data);

        });


    });
}

getData2()
```

Comment: I don't see console.log(results); in your code change? That was my point for this question.

Comment: How can a console.log(results) be the point when "results" was empty, and you could add it yourself? Did you at least try to console.log it?

Comment: By the way, if you looked at the code, you would see that the issue with the empty array you had was due to the missing <td>...</td>. , hence why console.log(results) was giving nothing. I posted this code here because you can't add code as a comment and because there were a. couple of issues like the process.exit() in your code.